# Export a drop down to excel to filter the Excel data using EPPlus. Can we include drop down data from database?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I need to download the Excel report upon generating it using .NET c# EP Plus.

I tried using auto filter, pivoting the table to extract values from DB, but I couldn't reach the solution.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PTcF_Summary");
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
var pivotTable = ws.PivotTables[0]; //assuming that we have only have 1
string pivotField = pivotTable.Fields["Type"].ToString();
//pivotTable.PageFields.Add(pivotField);
var validation = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation("G2");
validation.Formula.Values.Add(pivotField);
ws.Cells["G2"].AutoFilter = true;
```

I expect the output as one cell in the excel should be a drop down showing the list of options through which I can filter the data of table in Excel. The filter should work like, on selecting a drop down value, if a particular column has it, then the respective row should be displayed and others should be filtered out. And upon selecting another drop down value, the same should happen vise versa.

Comment: dt is a data table